# Akeneo attribute regex wir OR "|" not working

Tags: regex, attributes, pipe, combinations, akeneo

The problem in Akeneo seems to be that simple regex combinations not working. I think the functionality (a single or group regex combination) is not integrated/implemented proper in Akeneo. If there is anybody out there who knows a trick to do a regex combination please let me know.

Tried to figure out how to make regex with `|` OR working in Akeneo "attributes".

the simple Example not working either a syntax error or no matching in Akeneo:

find this "323"
or find "123456"

```py
\d{3}|\d{6}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Thomas, you need to add exact details on what you get when using the pattern, and what you expected. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://help.akeneo.com/pim/v2/articles/what-is-an-attribute.html), you need to use regex literal notation, and anchor the match both at the start and end of the string (so, add a grouping):

```js
/^(\d{6}|\d{3})$/
```

Here, `/` are regex delimiters, `^` matches the start of string, `(...)` is a capturing group that contains two alternatives, six digits or three digits, and then end of string anchor, `$`, follows.